# capture Camera Image and put into Gridview

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. I use the bumtech glid library and when I click and try to capture a camera image it always become an error:

```
6-01 02:17:06.217 1696-1696/com.sportfriend.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sportfriend.app, PID: 1696
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Sportfriend/SF20170601021706.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:845)
at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8941)
at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8926)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
at com.sportfriend.app.GalleryActivityMain.cameraIntent(GalleryActivityMain.java:140)
at com.sportfriend.app.GalleryActivityMain.getPhoto(GalleryActivityMain.java:82)
at com.sportfriend.app.GalleryActivityMain.access$000(GalleryActivityMain.java:28)
at com.sportfriend.app.GalleryActivityMain$1.onClick(GalleryActivityMain.java:56)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Blockquote

```html
public class GalleryActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnPhoto;
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;
    private List<String> imageItems;
    private String imagePath="";
    private File myDir;
    private File filePath;
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_RESULT = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_gallery);

        createAppDirectory();

        imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Sportfriend";
        imageItems = new ArrayList<>();

        btnPhoto  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
        btnPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                getPhoto();

            }
        });
        getImages();

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item, imageItems);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                String imagePath = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryActivityMain.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imagePath", imagePath);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    }

    private void getPhoto(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                    cameraIntent();
                }else {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Berechtigung zum Speichern ben�tigt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT);
                }
            }else {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Berechtigung zum Speichern ben�tigt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_CAMERA_RESULT);
            }
        }else {
            cameraIntent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int [] grantResults){

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getPhoto();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Berechtigung verweigert !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_RESULT){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getPhoto();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, " Kein Zugriff auf Camera",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void createAppDirectory(){
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        myDir = new File(root + "/Sportfriend");
        if (!myDir.exists()){
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private void cameraIntent(){

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        String sDate = formatter.format(date);
        String imageName = "SF" + sDate + ".jpg";

        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            filePath = new File(myDir, imageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(filePath));

            startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            String errorText = "Funktion wird auf Ihren Ger�t nicht Unterst�tzt!";
            Toast.makeText(this, errorText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private List<String> getImages(){
        new File(imagePath ).mkdirs();

        File fileTarget = new File(imagePath);
        File[] files = fileTarget.listFiles();

        imageItems.clear();

        if (files!=null){
            for (File file: files){
                imageItems.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        return imageItems;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        getImages();
        gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }





}
```

A tried to use Fileprovider, but it doesn't run.

Comment: Are you targeting Sdk Version  24 or higher ?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: Hi, yes i use Sdk 24 +,,, i also tried at Sdk 22 with genymotion virtual device

Comment: i read this post already, but i dont find a way to use this code: Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", createImageFile()); in my camera Intent code

Comment: in your camera intent method appy condition to this line intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(filePath));

Answer (score 1):

```
private void cameraIntent()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
    {
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera");
        if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();
        File image = new File(path, "image.jpg");
        Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", image);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
    else
    {
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera");
        if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();
        File image = new File(path, "image.jpg");
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
}
```

Comment: schould i only use, the cameraIntent(); or should i also implent the above requestPermissioncode etc?